# seeking basic understanding of implementing Xmpp in PHP applications --

Tags: php, xmpp, openfire

I am new to xmpp and need to understand its basics for integrating it with my php application. I have set up Openfire server and want to use my preexisting mysql database to get the users. So as per the docs, i modified Openfires config xml file to add the database Auth and User settings.

Also the Xmpphp lib seems to be the right lib for me at this stage. I managed to make Xmpphp work with the google talk server as per the example provided. Now to use it with my app, i have following doubts -

while establshing the connection to the 5222 port, which username and passord do i have to provide for authentication ? of the user who is logged in to my app, or do i need to create new users from the openfire admin.

Also, i understand that i need to code an xmpp client on my website before i can do any testing...is there a way to find out if its working because right now even if I connect to the server using a certain username and password, it shows me a blank page.. (initially it showed me some errors which i got rid of) .
kindly help
regards

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/

Try this library and turn on display_errors, set error_reporting to E_ALL etc.